# Can anyone explain why the user is not being redirected to another page after login?

Tags: authentication, redirect, indexing, widget, netlify

I coded this login form using the Netlify identity widget saying if user is authenticated to redirect them to my index3.html page; however, after logging in it doesn not execute the function. I tried posting this issue on the Netlify forum, but it won't allow the pasting of the code for some reason.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- include the widget -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://identity.netlify.com/v1/netlify-identity-    widget.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Add a menu:
Log in / Sign up - when the user is not logged in
Username / Log out - when the user is logged in
-->
<div data-netlify-identity-menu></div>

<!-- Add a simpler button:
 Simple button that will open the modal.
-->
<div data-netlify-identity-button>Login with Netlify Identity</div>
</body>
<script>
// Get the current user:
// Available after on('init') is invoked
const user = netlifyIdentity.currentUser();

// Bind to events
netlifyIdentity.on('init', user => console.log('init', user));
netlifyIdentity.on('login', user => console.log('login', user));
netlifyIdentity.on('logout', () => console.log('Logged out'));
netlifyIdentity.on('error', err => console.error('Error', err));
netlifyIdentity.on('open', () => console.log('Widget opened'));
netlifyIdentity.on('close', () => console.log('Widget closed'));

// Unbind from events
netlifyIdentity.off('login'); // to unbind all registered handlers
netlifyIdentity.off('login', handler); // to unbind a single handler

// Close the modal
netlifyIdentity.close();

// Log out the user
netlifyIdentity.logout();

// Refresh the user's JWT
// Call in on('login') handler to ensure token refreshed after it expires (1hr)  
// Note: this method returns a promise.
netlifyIdentity.refresh().then((jwt)=>console.log(jwt))

// Change language
netlifyIdentity.setLocale('en');

// Check if user is authenticated
if (!user) {
// Redirect to login page or other desired page
window.location.href = 'https://pieconfidential.com/index3.html'; // Replace with your  desired URL
```

}

```
// Check if Netlify Identity is fully initialized
if (netlifyIdentity.isInitialized()) {
const user = netlifyIdentity.currentUser();
// Your redirect logic here
} else {
// If not fully initialized, wait for the 'init' event
netlifyIdentity.on('init', () => {
  const user = netlifyIdentity.currentUser();
  // Your redirect logic here
});
}

</script>

</html>
```

I tried copying and pasting the exact code Netlify has on its support forums for the simple Netlify widget sign up/log in code, then I added some additional code to see if it would rectify the issue to no avail. I expected the redirect to desired page would work. At one time I had the function execute, but it skipped over logging in the index page, and instead wen't directly to the redirect page. With the code in the current state, I log in and the page just stays there reading "user logged in".